# I wrote a web page and want to display on the phone. How do I adjust the background image?

Tags: html

I wrote a web page and I want to display it on a phone now, but the background picture is too big to display fully, how to adjust?

```
<td width="60%" height="105" background="templets/images/top_logo.jpg" align="left">
```

It is normal in the computer web browser, but on the phone, it can shows only a part of the image, not scaled down.

I assume that there's a simple, one- or two-liner to make this happen. Where can I find an example of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a set to the webview
for example

```
//adapt to print 39adapt to the vertical screen 57adapt to cross scree
mWebView.setInitialScale(39)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com). It helps in all mobile platforms like android,iphone and blackberry.